# Fetch data from mysql using associative array and implode (codeigniter + MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've gathered data from multiple MySql tables and stored them as associative arrays using a foreach loop with the query.

I would like to use those associative arrays and the implode method in the mysql query to gather more data from a separate table.

I know that with the implode method, when dealing with Indexed arrays, you can just insert the array directly in the "implode section". But with associative arrays, I am unsure how to call all the available arrays and insert them in the query.

Please refer to the attached image for a detailed illustration explaining it further.

Below is also a portion of my code

```
public function user_implode()
{

        $s_id = array(
          "id" => 383
        );

        $count = 0; 
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {   
                $count = $count + 1;
                $loop_number[$count] =  $row->id; 

            }

        $this->db->from('occupation');
        $this->db->where_in('id',implode("','",$loop_number[$count]));
        $query = $this->db->get();



        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {

                echo $row->id;

        }

        echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();

}
```

THANKS ALOT [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to [`where_in()`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) should be an array.

You are generating a string with `implode()` and only of the last value of the array instead of the whole array.

So all you need is:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $loop_number);
```

And I don't see where `$query` comes from, it seems to be undefined when you use it in the first loop in your method.

Apart from that you should initialize your variable, `$loop_number = [];` before the loop.

Comment: Thanks very much my friend. This is very well explained. And thanks for the additional tip for initiating variables :)